# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object while looping in computed field

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion, odoo

i need to make a computed method to calculate the range of years on fire while importing excel sheet 
if it onChange without dependence api it work well when i but manually records into fields but also not work while importing data

i trired this code but when i'am importing data or inter record into fields i get an error as a title and below

```
class relate(models.Model):
_name = 'relate'
_rec_name = 'car'

@api.multi
@api.depends('start', 'end', 'ignore')
def years_rang(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.start and rec.end:
            record = [int(x) for x in range(int(rec.start), int(rec.end) + 1)]
            list = []
            if rec.ignore:
                try:
                    record.remove(int(self.ignore))
                    list = []
                except ValueError:
                    return {'warning': {'title': 'Warning!', 'message': "the Ignored year doesn't in range"}}
            for item in record:
                range_id = self.env['yearrange'].create({'name': str(item)})
                list.append(range_id.id)
            rec.rang = [(4, x, None) for x in list]
        pass
start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", inverse_name="product_id", store=True, string="Years" ,compute="years_rang")
ignore = fields.Char(string="Ignore", required=False, )


class yearrange(models.Model):
_name = 'yearrange'
_rec_name = 'name'

name = fields.Char()
product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="relate")
```

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Please, post the relevant part of the stack trace, or a [mcve]. This error means, literally, that you "exceeded the maximum recursion depth". But here, there doesn't seem to be any recursion : I don't think the problem is here.

Comment: actually  here is the problem because of if i changed api depends to onchange and remove the compute attrs it working well

Comment: and never name your list `list` or a variable `id`, for example here you cannot create a list after defining that variable like this , `x = list(y)` avoid this.